# How to capture small changes in the canvas and send them to all the users connected to each other who are also using that canvas?

Tags: html, node.js, canvas, websocket, socket.io

i want to allow people to communicate via html5 canvas. If one person draws on his canvas, the other should be able to see it simultaneously and vice-verse.

I'm using node.js as the server with express framework and socket.io .

There are methods like .toDataURL and other method is to convert it into blob and then send it. But these methods convert the entire canvas into an image and then send them via websockets.

Is there an efficient way by which i can only send the new data created or the changes made in the canvas instead of creating an image and then sending it again n again to all the users ?

Is it better to keep the track of pixels ?

Comment: How is the new data created? You'd want to send those same instructions to other clients rather than the full canvas.

Comment: new data is created when a user draws/erases on the canvas. Example is if a user A makes a line in the canvas, the same should be reflected in User B's canvas

Comment: Right, so you'd send the "draw line" instruction to User B's canvas.

Comment: but how shall i send the information like thickness of a line,color,etc

Comment: Send it as a tiny json doc: `{ instruction: 'drawLine', x1: 10, y1: 10, x2: 250, y2: 100, thickness: 2, color: 'ff0000' }`.

Comment: i cannot just take the start and end points only, because if i make a shape similar to parabola then instead of a parabola the user B will receive only end points by which he will draw a straight line.

Comment: You need to think through this a bit more. Why would you send a line if they drew a parabola? You'd send the instruction for `"drawParabola"`.

Answer (score 2):

"methods convert the entire canvas into an image" - instead of sending the canvas data(image) you need to send user interactions.

Correct way of going ahead is to first record user actions(click, drag etc), serialize them and then send them to other users who are sharing this canvas. The receivers must playback the received actions on their canvas to give an effect of shared canvas.

You may find this useful: http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/deserializing-recordings-in-recordable-html5-canvas/

Comment: But the idea explained in the link, is very tedious for the user. As no user would like to again and again click buttons for small moves

Comment: Please care your query is bit too broad to be answered directly. I have tried to point to a functional way of implementing your requirement. There may be comprehensive solutions that might reduce overall effort but eventually user's canvas interactions need to be recorded, serialized and transmitted to enable any kind of canvas sharing. Good luck!

Comment: Recording is not necessary. I used the mouseup and mousedown events and emitted the co-ordinates to the server